# C# Accessing DropDownList item values that sit within a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a a generic control called dropdownlist.ascx that populates it's ListItems based on a XML document and a property that I pass to this control.

This control is used multiple times on the same aspx page. I have no problem casting this control as a DropDownList control in the Page_Load event of the aspx page, however when I want to set the SelectedValues of this control on the Page_Load event of the aspx page it doesn't work as the Items.Count value is 0.

I assume there are some Page Lifecyle issues going on here.

**Control on page.aspx**

```
<triangle:DDLResponse ID="ddlHeight" runat="server" CssClass="dropdownlist ddlregister" responseId="height" mode="dropdownlist" />
```

**Codebehind on page.aspx**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        UserProfile profile = controls_session.profile;

        DropDownList _ddlHeight = (DropDownList)ddlHeight.FindControl("dropdownlist");

        _ddlHeight.SelectedValue = profile.Height;          

    }
}
```

The List Items of ddlHeight render without issue.

Anyone have any idea or solution to this?

Thanks,

Comment: This looks OK to me. The only thing I can think of is that your ascx file is named dropdownlist which may be conflicting with System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `SelectedValue` in `Page_PreRender` event. It will work.

Comment: I actually just got this to work but by setting the Page_Load event of my usercontrol to Page_Init so that it renders before the ASPX page does.

Comment: You DropDownList most likely hasn't been databound (.DataBind()) yet in PageLoad so indeed doing it in PreRender should work.